# Drop Down List Selected Value Gets Reset On PostBack When Getting Disabled With JQuery

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have this issue where if I disable a control with JQuery on the .change event of a drop down list, the control's gets reset to its default state.

I have the following code:

ASP.NET:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>

</head>

<script type='text/javascript' src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
    <asp:ListItem Value="1">Item1</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="2">Item2</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
</div>
</form>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#DropDownList1").change(function () {

    $("#DropDownList1").attr("disabled", "disabled");

});
</script>
</html>
```

Code Behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class _default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

So with that code, if you switch the selected item from `DropDownList1` it will be reset on PostBack to its default state. If the control is not being disabled with Jquery, it does not reset the control.

How to make it keep its value on PostBack while being disabled?

Comment: What you need, cancel postback?

Comment: You will probably need to store the current state of JavaScript in the sessionstate object and recall that on postbacks.

Comment: I will be trying this right now Chris.

Comment: But If you need that make a postback, Why not disable the DDL in the onselecteIndexchange, easy and without complications.

Comment: The value still gets reseted on postback

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the `Autopostback="True"` so that no postbacks takes place..

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Value="1">Item1</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="2">Item2</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

`Autopostback="True"` is set whenever you have to do something on the code behind when changing dropdown item..

Try disabling like this..

```
$("#DropDownList1").attr("disabled", true);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. My requirement needs that this drop down list does a post back. The only thing I am trying to do is disable temporarily the drop down before the post back is done. I just don't understand why the drop down list keeps its value when it does not get disabled before post back.

Comment: Is the dropdown get disabled after postback?

Comment: No it is reseted to its default state. (selectedindex = 0 and enabled = true)

Comment: So do you prefer disabling the control inside code behind event..such as Selectedindexchanged,Regards..

Comment: It is working fine when I disable the Dropdown on Selectedindexchanged..It is not resetting the selected item..

Comment: Yes it works, but the thing is I want to disable it temporarily before the PostBack happens. Changing it into the SelectedIndexChanged event will only happen after the PostBack.